# The scope of the Universe of Integers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have this question:

Let $P(x, y)$ be the proposition $x^2 = y$, where $x$ and $y$ are in the universe of integers. Determine the truth value of each of the following propositions.

for:  $\exists x/ P(x, 6)$

Im wondering if in discrete maths the universe of integers include numbers inbetween whole numbers? (ie floating point numbers, $7.5$, $3.146$ etc)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I mean, why would they bother saying "in the universe of integers", if that were the case?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Integers are ... *integers*. $7.5$ is "seven and an half", which is not "integer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set of integers $\mathbb{Z}$ is defined as $\mathbb{N} \cup \{-n, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

So, no, there are no such elements inbetween.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't; $\Bbb Z=\Bbb N\cup\{0\}\cup\{-n\mid n\in \Bbb N\}$.